# UpdateModel with SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

I have class named Product

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Please tell me how to update Category with UpdateModel method.

Below you'll find category code in View

Answer (score 1):

I've found a easier way do do it:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Category.Id", (System.Web.Mvc.SelectList) ViewData["categoryList"])%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating `ViewData["categoryList"]` like this:

```
ViewData["categoryList"] = categories.Select(
    category => new SelectListItem {
        Text = category.Title,
        Value = category.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
```

then in your POST action, you can simply update your Product.Category property:

```
int categoryId;
int.Parse(Request.Form["Category"], out categoryId);

product.Category = categories.First(x => x.Id == categoryId);
```

or create custom ModelBinder for updating with UpdateModel():

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (String.Compare(propertyDescriptor.Name, "Category", true) == 0)
        {
            int categoryId = (int)bindingContext.ValueProvider["tags"].RawValue;

            var product = bindingContext.Model as Product;

            product.Category = categories.First(x => x.Id == categoryId);

            return;
        }

        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
}
```